# Javascript not applying on Icon

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```js
function addGlobalEventListener(type, selector, callback) {
  document.addEventListener(type, function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e);
  });
}


addGlobalEventListener('click', '.js-accordation', function(e) {
  let panel = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  e.target.classList.toggle('js-accordation_is-active');
  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null
  } else panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

```html
<div class="js-accordation">ACCORDATION
  <i class="icon icon_arrow-down"></i>
</div>
```

When I click *ACCORDATION* it's working but When I click on icon, it's not working

Comment: You check if it matches the selector: `if (e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e);` If you click on the icon, `e.target` will be `.icon` and not `.js-accordation` .

Comment: Try `currentTarget` instead of `target` to actually make use of event propagation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your event listener is only triggering when a class with `js-accordation` is clicked.

You can add more selector in your `addGlobalEventListener` and add the `i` tag:

```
addGlobalEventListener('click',['.js-accordation', '.js-accordation i'],function(e){}
```

```js
function addGlobalEventListener (type, selector, callback){ document.addEventListener(type,function(e){
  if(e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e);
 });
}


addGlobalEventListener('click',['.js-accordation', '.js-accordation i'],function(e){
 console.log('accordation');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div  class="js-accordation">ACCORDATION
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</div>
```